# why Image from SD Card isn't displayed?

Tags: android, image, storage

I used this code to display image from SD Card. The result shows that the path exist and it is correct but no image appeared.
How can I solve this problem ?

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView processedImgA;
    static String imgSouce = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/folder/image.jpg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        processedImgA = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.processedimg_a);

        Bitmap bitmap_Source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgSouce);

        processedImgA.setImageBitmap(bitmap_Source);


    }



}
```

Comment: If you try to access SD Card using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, then android considers it as an Internal Storage, as for Android OS, even your internal storage is taken by `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: you have to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for it and after android 6.0 ask run time permission to user. Also remember about FileProvider you have to add your share directory path manifest file. https://blog.stylingandroid.com/fileprovider/

Comment: I add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but it doesnt ask me the permission in the app after

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String imgSouce = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/folder/image.jpg";
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgSouce, bmOptions);
processedImgA.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

ALSO make sure you added `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and checked runtime for 6.0 devises

Answer (score 0):

If your app's targetAPI is 23+(Android 6.0+) then you should request read permission before read file from storage sdcard.
My advice you can use rxpermission to request permission.

```
implementation com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar//for add rxpermissions
implementation io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.4//for add rxjava
```

//you should add two lines code above in app/build.gradle file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView processedImgA;
    static String imgSouce = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/folder/image.jpg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RxPermissions rxpermission = new RxPermissions(this);
        rxpermission.
        processedImgA = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.processedimg_a);
        request(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        .subscribe(grated->{
            if (!grated) {
                //toast permission denied
            }else{
                //read bitmap in here
                 Bitmap bitmap_Source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgSouce);

                 processedImgA.setImageBitmap(bitmap_Source);  
            }
        });

    }

}
```